# ¿Cómo calcular la cantidad de noches entre dos fechas SQL?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es una fórmula que me vaya calculando el total de días entre ArrivalDate y DepartureDate y el resultado lo vaya indicando de una vez dentro del registro como una columna adicional de la consulta que sea por ejemplo TotalStay y el número de días que se calculó anteriormente.

Comment: Por favor, **crea un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Además, ¿cómo determinas una noche?

Comment: Gio Gómez, ya has recibido una respuesta, pero todavía no has definido que es una "noche", tal como te lo preguntan más arriba. Si la noche es efectivamente esa porción del día dónde el sol se oculta, la respuesta no te sirve, por que solo te da la diferencia en días. Tampoco has agregado ninguna definición de la estructura de la tabla, el enlace que te pasaron describe como escribir una pregunta para que sea bien recibida, sino eventualmente podría terminar cerrada. Saludos.

Comment: En lugar de dejar una imagen cortada coloca el código como texto en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

La funcion de sql server que estas buscando es datediff, se usa asi :

```
DEclare @arrival datetime, @departure datetime

set @arrival = '2005-10-11 00:00:00'
set @departure = '2005-10-29 00:00:00'

select DateDiff(day, @arrival, @departure)
```

Esta funcion puedes llamarla como parte de cualquier consulta, para despues almacenarla en la tabla que desees, espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: Esta función está bien, pero el problema es que son 1500 registros y tendría que variar el script para cada uno de ellos, alguna forma de que lo vaya calculando registro por registro?

Comment: Usando la función que te dio Mauricio Select DateDiff(day, ArrivalDate , DepartureDate ) As Periodo From TuTabla @GioGómez, el resto quedaria definir que periodo de tiempo se considera una noche

Comment: Cómo podría implementarlo en una consulta que ya tengo?

Comment: Como se llaman los campos arrival y departure dentro de la consulta ?